# phpmyadmin not working on nginx web server in linux ami on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

What I am working with :
Instance - amazon EC2,
OS - linux AMI,
Web-server - nginx

I have installed phpmyadmin according to what is mentioned in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

I have mysql up and running, as well as php-fpm and nginx. I also created a symlink between the directory where phpMyAdmin i.e /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin -> /usr/share/nginx/www/html

below is what I have in my nginx.conf file

```
server{
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        #location ^~ /phpMyAdmin/ { 
        #   root /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin; 
        #   index index.php; 
        #   include fastcgi_params; 
        #   fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        #   fastcgi_index index.php; 
        #   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME script/$fastcgi_script_name; 
        #} 

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root             /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin;
            fastcgi_index    index.php;
        fastcgi_pass     unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        include          fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }   
    }
```

But none of this seems to work. I am trying from hours but unable to figure out what may be the problem due to which its not working. any help would be really great. Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is the problem — what error message are you seeing in your browser, what do the error logs say, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below vhost config file. Error page redirection handling appears a problem with your config file.

```
server {

listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin; # Change the PHPMyAdmin location
    index index.php;

    server_name default_server;# Set server name based on sub-domain

    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpMyAdmin-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/phpMyAdmin-error.log notice;

    charset utf-8;
    error_page 404 403 500 502 503 504 /index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ico|swf)$ { expires 365d; access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; allow all; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        expires off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/phpmyadmin.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```